# Looping Through PHP Array from SQL

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code, which Im using to try loop through an array, however it is printing nothing:

```
$getdata = "SELECT TimeDate, Percent FROM UserHistory";
echo $getdata;
$dataresult = mysqli_query($con,$getdata);
while($datarray = mysqli_fetch_array($dataresult));
{
    echo $datarray['TimeDate'];
}
```

If I replace the while loop with `$datarray = mysqli_fetch_array($dataresult);` and then `echo $datarray[0]` or `echo $datarray[1]` it prints out values, but only the first set of results.

Comment: are you using fetch_array or fetch_assoc?

Comment: Accepting someone else answer after using my solution... `-1`. This will cause that I won't help anyone anymore in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ';' from while($datarray = mysqli_fetch_array($dataresult));

Comment: Wow, accepted answer that does not fix the problem. How nice.

Comment: Flash, You should compare your original answer with the accepted answer not the edited one. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: But you still have to change _array to _assoc

Answer (score 3):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` and everything will be fine.

`mysqli_fetch_array` does not assign column names as indexes. Thats why numeric indexes work, but named inexes don't.

There is an error in code too... `;` finishes `while` in a line it starts. Remove it.

Comment: I replaced `mysqli_fetch_array` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and still nothing is printed out